# Get value of attribute in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to isolate the `"ip"` attribute of a `JSON` object. The code that gets the `JSON` object is

```
var parsed;
$.getJSON('//jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(data) {
    parsed = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    console.log(parsed);
});
```

it returns this JSON object.

```
{
  "ip": "118.210.141.127",
  "about": "/about",
  "Pro!": "http://getjsonip.com",
  "reject-fascism": "Women make their own choices. Support abortion rights."
}
```

For some reason `parsed.ip` returns undefined, not `"118.210.141.127"` how do I access the ip value properly?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are trying to access `parsed.ip` ?
I suscpect that you might be trying to access is before the JSON is returned from server. Due to the async nature of `.getJSON`

Comment: `document.getElementById("welcomeIP").innerHTML = parsedip.ip;` is the next line in the program which changes the value of that element to `unedefined` :)

Comment: in the above code your object is `parsed` but in your innerHTML comment you refer to `parsedip`. There's no such object as `parsedip` defined. Typo?

Comment: Also JSON.stringify turns your object into a string, which isn't helpful, because it no longer has any properties, it's just a string. `console.log(data.ip);` should get you the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> parsed = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
> ```

JSON.stringify does the **oposite** of parsing data. It converts a JS data structure into JSON, not the other way around. `parsed.ip` will then string to read the `ip` property of a *string* instead of the parsed object.

`getJSON` will parse the JSON for you automatically. So just don't mess around with it.

```
$.getJSON('//jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data.ip);
});
```

You might also need to remove `?callback=?` from the URL. That is used when you expect a JSONP response, not a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$.getJSON('//jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data.ip); // should output 118.210.141.127
});
```

When you call [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), the success function will eventually be executed with the parsed JavaScript object, not the JSON string.

So when you do `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)`, you are converting the JavaScript object back to a JSON string.

Comment: "jQuery.getJSON() returns the parsed JavaScript object" — It **returns** a promise-like object. The parsed JSON (which is an object in this case but doesn't have to be) will be the argument to the success function.